# Website Collapses to fit Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorrry i am new in this

After creating my website and tested it on my desktop, everything looks to work great while trying to drag the browser window the divs works perfect.

But while testing it on mobile phones, it worked on blackberry and didnt work on samsung galaxi note 2

here is the link:
http://goo.gl/JLXDGI

Please help

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly didn't work on the Note 2?

Comment: Thank you Nick For your turnover and your will to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add the viewport tag to your `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">
```

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: THANK YOU A LOTTTTTTTT OSCAR.it worked just fine.

Comment: @user2776769 No worries, catches me out everytime!